# Spark List control - 'n' key moves to next row

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I've created an editable list. It means I have an sparks:List with itemRenderes with TextInputs. When I type in text fields, the 'n' key moves selection to next list item. How to get rid of this ? Before Flash Player update the 't' key moved me to the first list item. Now it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've got it. If someone needs a solution :

Just add an high priority event handler :

```
this.articleList.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, 
articleList_keyDownHandler, false, int.MAX_VALUE);
```

and the handler :

```
protected function articleList_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```